# Mstest OwnerAttribute on class level

Tags: .net, mstest

I want to keep owner information on class level for my mstest classes. There is OwnerAttribute but it can be attached only to TestMethod not TestClass. There is also other mstest attribute that could be utilized for that purpose but all they can be set only on TestMethod level as well. Does anybody have any solution to define owner on TestClass level?

Comment: What is this attribute actually for? Is it utilized programmatically in some way or is it essentially a comment encapsulated in an attribute?

Comment: Data from this attribute goes into Owner tag of final report